# Problems with lag using LG DualUp display with Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon; works fine with MacBook Pro

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, lg-monitor

I recently got an LG DualUp for work and my main computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 6, closing in on 5ish years old. The monitor seems to work fine when connected to a MacBook Pro, but I've had a few annoying issues dealing with the Thinkpad.

1. Mouse and keyboard input are really laggy. It's as if I'm getting about 8 frames per second with keyboard and mouse input on the external monitor (*not* on the main laptop screen, which is perfectly fine). This doesn't happen with the MacBook. This is also despite the fact that the monitor's refresh rate is 29.957Hz (the max available in the Display Settings). In fact, *video plays fine* with no lag on the monitor. Seems like other functions like moving windows around, scrolling, etc. are also lagging but it's hard to tell exactly which part is laggy.
2. Occasionally, the mouse cursor will jump from its position on the laptop screen to the same position on the external monitor, with no input on my part. Seems to only happen when the cursor has been idle.
3. It's hard to tell, but I'm fairly certain that the Thinkpad is slower overall when connected to the monitor. Simple functions like minimizing windows, opening file explorer, etc. take way longer (not a display related issue) when connected.

Some other notes:

- I installed both LG OnScreen Control (to split the monitor vertically) and LG Dual Controller (to see if I could use my MacBook as the main monitor and the Thinkpad as secondary, but this had its own separate issues). Lag on the external monitor was present before and after installing these utilities.
- The only connection available between the monitor and the Thinkpad is HDMI. Neither USB-C nor USB-to-DisplayPort work with the Thinkpad, however USB-C works with the MacBook. I tried multiple different HDMI cables and neither made any difference - both worked with the MacBook however.
- The Thinkpad's display adapter is an Intel UHD Graphics 620.
- I can't tell if I have the right drivers installed for the external monitor (do I need any?)

Anyone had any similar troubles with this monitor/laptop setup? How can I diagnose the slowdowns caused by connecting the monitor? Is it possible my processor is simply too slow for this? Pretty disappointed as the Thinkpad is my primary device for the time being.

Comment: My guess right now is that the HDMI port on the ThinkPad is version 1.4b, whereas on the MacBook it's 2.0 - maybe 1.4b simply can't transfer input to a display of this size as effectively? (It is odd that I can only get up to 29.957Hz, as per this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1773183/why-my-75hz-monitor-shows-only-29hz-refresh-rate)